# Creating a recursive function in Python 3

Tags: python, list, recursion

So far, this is what I have right now

```
class X:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

def linkedlist(l):
    if l == []:
        return None
    beg = end = X(l[0])
        for v in l[1:]:
            end.next = X(v)
            end = end.next
    return beg

lst1 = linkedlist(['a', 'b', 'c''])
lst2 = linkedlist(['a', 'b', 'c'])
lst3 = linkedlist(['c', 'a', 'b'])
```

I am trying to create a recursive function that will determine whether the two linked lists, lst 1 and lst 2, are the same. If they are, it will return True, else False.

```
def is_same(lst1, lst2):
    if lst1.next == None or lst2.next == None: 
        return None 
    else:
        if lst1.next == lst2.next:
            return X(is_same(lst1.next, lst2.next))
        else:
            return True
```

I know my recursive function is wrong, but I am having trouble because it keeps giving me errors. The "is_same" function is returning True everytime I put:

```
is_same(lst1, lst2)
is_same(lst1, lst3) # This should be False
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems.

1. This does not handle empty lists (`None`).
2. `lst1.next == lst2.next` compares nodes, not values.
3. The first values are never compared.
4. You are calling the constructor `X` for some reason.

I think you want something like this

```
def is_same(lst1, lst2):
    return not lst1 and not lst2      \ 
        or lst1 and lst2              \
        and lst1.value == lst2.value  \
        and is_same(lst1.next, lst2.next)
```

Optionally, you may wish to throw in parantheses for clarity (in case someone doesn't know about order of operations for `and` and `or`).

```
def is_same(lst1, lst2):
    return (not lst1 and not lst2) or (
        lst1 and lst2
        and lst1.value == lst2.value
        and is_same(lst1.next, lst2.next)
    )
```

EDIT: Or, for fewer boolean operations,

```
def is_same(lst1, lst2):
    if lst1:
        return lst2                       \
            and lst1.value == lst2.value  \
            and is_same(lst1.next, lst2.next)
    return not lst2
```

Comment: `not lst1 and not lst2` can be expressed as `lst1 == lst2 == None` in Python.

Comment: It means that the next line is not a logical new line by a continuation.